# Detect whether Motion & Orientation Access is enabled in Javascript - iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-safari

Unfortunately Safari disables Motion and Orientation access by default in:

*Settings > Safari > Privacy & Security > Motion & Orientation Access*

So what I'm trying to figure out is if it's possible to detect whether the user has this setting enabled or not. Is there a property on the window object in the browser that informs me that it's enabled?

I've tried looking up the solution on StackOverflow and various other places but they're either outdated or just don't work.

Comment: It seems Safari on iOS supports `window.orientation`. What value does that return when access is disabled?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but what Modernizr does is probably the best you're gonna get: `'DeviceMotionEvent' in window`, `'DeviceOrientationEvent' in window` (see https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/a747f33b2bc5db186f18bca4d1d63bf503d3159d/feature-detects/event/deviceorientation-motion.js)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **window.orientation** property (output will be in degrees), since it is supported in Safari for IOS

**Note:** Its use is depreciated and is not supported in many of the other browsers, fore other browsers you should use the **screen.orientation** property or the **Generic Sensors API**